# Denoising Not Showing In Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers, denoise

Ive gotten blend 2.79b and I heard about the denoising feature. I went into the render layers tab but it's no were to be found. I'm in cycles render.
[image: Cycles Scene]

Comment: Your screenshot shows you using version 2.76 so no denoiser...

Answer (score 2):

The image posted as part of the question shows that you are using an old version of blender (2.76).

Denoiser was introduced in [version 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles)

Comment: It could be that you downloaded 2.79, but are still running 2.76. they will be shown as two separate programs on your PC, you should uninstall 2.76 to make sure you always click on 2.79